# Binding different Models/pPoperties in the same ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is currently bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `strings`. For each item in the `ItemsSource`, two `comboboxes` and one `textblock` will appear.

Now, I have two different models, only one instance of each. The first `combobox` lists the names of these models. When chosen, I want the second `combobox` to populate with an `ObservableCollection` of strings representing the different fields in these models. Finally, the `textblock` will show the value of the chosen field from the second `combobox`.

Basically my problem is, I'm not creating new instances of these models every time I add an item to the first collection. That's just a dummy collection to make the controls appear. As I said above, I only have one instance of each of the six models that I want to bind to. The same model/property could be displayed multiple times over different combobox/textblock sets.

My ModelBase class, DataModel + two sample models are below. Each has an `observablecollection` containing strings representing the properties in the models (not showing all of them, but they are all strings):

```
public abstract class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _fieldList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    {
        get { return _fieldList; }
    }

    private ObservablePairCollection<string, string> _fields = new ObservablePairCollection<string, string>();
    public override ObservablePairCollection<string, string> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name { 
        get { return _name; }
        protected set {
            if (_name != value) {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}

public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ModelBase> models = new ObservableCollection<ModelBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> Models
    {
        get { return models; }
        set { models = value; OnPropertyChanged("Models"); }
    }

    private ModelBase _selectedModel;
    public ModelBase SelectedModel
    {
        get { return _selectedModel; }
        set { _selectedModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedModel"); }
    }

    private object _selectedField;
    public object SelectedField
    {
        get { return _selectedField; }
        set { _selectedField = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedField"); }
    }
}

public class GPHDTModel: ModelBase
{
    public GPHDTModel()
    {
        //  It's a bad and dangerous habit to mess with private fields. 
        //  Nothing but the public property's get/set blocks should touch the 
        //  private field. One day you'll set _name and wonder why PropertyChanged
        //  wasn't raised. Make a habit of avoiding that risk. 
        Fields.Add("MessageID", "");
        Name = "GPHDT";
    }

    public string MessageID
    {
        get { return Fields[0].Value; }
        set { Fields[0].Value = value; OnPropertyChanged("MessageID"); }
    }
}

public class PASHRModel: ModelBase
{
    public PASHRModel()
    {
        Fields.Add("Heading", "");
        Name = "PASHR";
    }

    public string Heading
    {
        get { return Fields[0].Value; }
        set { Fields[0].Value = value; OnPropertyChanged("Heading"); }
    }
}
```

Relevant parts of the viewmodel below. The `DataModelCollection` is just a collection of `DataModel`s. The `NmeaType` collection is what the first combobox in each set of items should bind to. And then there's the six instances of my Models:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _dataModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> DataModelCollection
    {
        get { return _dataModelCollection; }
        set { _dataModelCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataModelCollection"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ModelBase> models = new ObservableCollection<ModelBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelBase> Models
    {
        get { return models; }
        set { models = value; OnPropertyChanged("Models"); }
    }        

    GPHDTModel gphdgModel = new GPHDTModel();
    PASHRModel pashrModel = new PASHRModel();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //add each NMEA model to the dictionary
        models.Add(gphdtModel);
        models.Add(pashrModel);
    }

    public void AddDataModel(object parameter)
    {
        DataModelCollection.Add(new DataModel { Models = models });
    }
}
```

Finally my view.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <ComboBox x:Name="NMEAlist"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNmeaString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ModelList"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedNmeaString.Fields, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedField, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value,
                                          ElementName=ModelList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />                                
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: _"I can't bind the controls in the ItemsControl to one property/collection since it's six different ones"_ -- of course you can. Make a single property that presents a different model object depending on the selection in the first `ComboBox`. You can even make the fisrt `ComboBox` items each view model. Unfortunately, you have not followed the guidelines at [mcve]; the above doesn't compile and contains much more code than seems to be necessary given your problem description. If you can improve the question to meet Stack Overflow standards, an actual answer could be provided.

Comment: Not exactly sure what to exclude from the question, all the code is relevant and needed to get the full picture in my opinion. When you say "make a single property", do you mean a property bound to the `ComboBox` selection?

Comment: Populate the ItemsControl with a collection of objects. Each object has two properties: The string that you've got now, and the model. That makes it very easy. This should be a snap. Doing it any other way makes it difficult -- for no reason. You'll probably need a different DataTemplate for each model type, but that's no big deal.

Comment: _"all the code is relevant and needed to get the full picture in my opinion"_ -- for starters, I doubt you need **six** different types to illustrate the question. Two ought to be sufficient. For another, I doubt that `AddDataModelCmd` is actually relevant. The binding issues can and should be illustrated without the distraction of a command in the question. There are a number of other things you can pare down as well. Just as pertinent is that the example is not **complete**. Again, see [mcve]. See also [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Deleted some code that wasn't necessary. I've tried what @EdPlunkett suggested, but it doesn't make sense to me. You say one of the properties is "the" model. I have multiple models, one instance of each.

Comment: Imagine a class that has two properties. Imagine creating six instances of that class. Six models. One per instance of that class. Each instance gets one model and one string.

Comment: Can you show me what you tried?

Comment: Edited post with what I have so far. I think I understand what you're saying now. But since an infinite number of combobox sets can be added, how would I keep adding items to the ItemsControl without adding repeats of the DataModel?

Comment: Still having trouble with this. I did a work-around with a dictionary, but I know it's not the right way to implement this and would still like some help if possible. @EdPlunkett

Comment: What is `DataModelCollection`? What is `DataModel`? Why do you have more than one item in your ItemsCollection? What do those items represent?

Comment: In your ItemTemplate for the ItemsControl, the DataContext in the DataTemplate will be `DataModel`, because those are the items in the collection that you bound to ItemsControl.ItemsSource. That means that in the DataTemplate, you are binding controls to properties of one instance of `DataModel`.

Comment: Updated my post, think I'm getting close. My `DataModel` class contains a collection of objects which are my six models. The first combobox is bound to the `Name` property in each of the models. Then the `selectedItem` is bound to a dictionary in each of my models, with the key being what is displayed in the second combobox, and the value being used in the textbox.

Comment: I'd like to suggest giving your models -- `GPHDTModel`, etc. -- all a common base class, with a `Name` property, an abstract `FieldList` property, etc. Call it `ModelBase`. Then `Models` would be `ObservableCollection<ModelBase>`, `SelectedNmeaString` would (I think, maybe) become `public ModelBase SelectedModel { ... }`, etc. The XAML won't care, but I will, and you will a month from now when you go back to fix a bug and try to figure this all out.

Comment: Second, I don't understand why `DataModelCollection` and `Models` are properties of the same class. I don't see how your DataTemplate can possibly work. Does `DataModel` have a `Models` property too?

Comment: Yes they both do. I was passing the `Models` in my viewmodel to each `DataModel` that was created. I'm going to create the base class now as you suggested.

Comment: Updated the post with a base model, does that look correct?

Comment: Thanks. I've made some suggested changes

Comment: Thanks for all you're help, it's much appreciated. I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the best answer, but it certainly should be able to accomplish what you want.

I would perhaps suggest using a converter. Assuming you already know what all these values are and all the collections you would like to return. The example I will show, will give you a basic concept, however you will need to orchestrate it to your liking.

Anyways, first create a converter:

```
public class StringToNmeaConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string sValue = (string)value;
        if (sValue == "PASHR")
        {
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<string>()
                {
                    "Foo",
                    "Bar",
                    "Foobar",
                    "Barfoo"
                };
            }
        }
        if (sValue == "GPGGA")
        {
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<string>()
                {
                    "Oof",
                    "Rab",
                    "Raboof",
                    "Oofrab"
                };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Then we want to have this converter in our XAML as a resource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StringToNmeaConverter x:Key="NmeaConverter"></local:StringToNmeaConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then we want to convert the combobox's selected item to the collection we want, and bind that to its item source.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="mainCombo">
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <sys:String>PASHR</sys:String>
                <sys:String>GPGGA</sys:String>
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="NmeaCombo" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainCombo, Path=SelectedItem, 
                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                  Converter={StaticResource NmeaConverter}}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=NmeaCombo, Path=SelectedItem, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```